# Export PivotTable with custom TableStyles on EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, epplus

I'm using EPPlus to export a pivot table. I was able to export all the data correctly and now I'm trying to set a custom style to my pivot table on excel, but I couldn't set a different style to it.

To do some tests, I'm using the 'Sample12.cs' that is available on the [GitHub Project][1]
[1]: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus

of EPPlus, here's the code:

```
    public static string RunSample12(string sqlServerName, DirectoryInfo outputDir)
    {
        var list = new List<SalesDTO>();
        if (sqlServerName == "")
        {
            list = GetRandomData();
        }
        else
        {
            list = GetDataFromSQL(sqlServerName);
        }

        string file = outputDir.FullName + @"\sample12.xlsx";
        if (File.Exists(file)) File.Delete(file);
        FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(file);

        using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
        {
            // get the handle to the existing worksheet
            var wsData = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("SalesData");

            var dataRange = wsData.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection
                (
                from s in list 
                orderby s.LastName, s.FirstName 
                select s, 
               true, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.None);                
            
            wsData.Cells[2, 6, dataRange.End.Row, 6].Style.Numberformat.Format = "mm-dd-yy";
            wsData.Cells[2, 7, dataRange.End.Row, 11].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0";
            
            dataRange.AutoFitColumns();

            var wsPivot = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("PivotSimple");
            var pivotTable1 = wsPivot.PivotTables.Add(wsPivot.Cells["A1"], dataRange, "PerEmploee");

            pivotTable1.RowFields.Add(pivotTable1.Fields[4]);
            var dataField = pivotTable1.DataFields.Add(pivotTable1.Fields[6]);
            dataField.Format="#,##0";
            pivotTable1.DataOnRows = true;

            var chart = wsPivot.Drawings.AddChart("PivotChart", eChartType.Pie, pivotTable1);
            chart.SetPosition(1, 0, 4, 0);
            chart.SetSize(600, 400);
                
            var wsPivot2 = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("PivotDateGrp");     
            var pivotTable2 = wsPivot2.PivotTables.Add(wsPivot2.Cells["A3"], dataRange, "PerEmploeeAndQuarter");

            pivotTable2.RowFields.Add(pivotTable2.Fields["Name"]);
                            

            //Add a rowfield
            var rowField = pivotTable2.RowFields.Add(pivotTable2.Fields["OrderDate"]);
            //This is a date field so we want to group by Years and quarters. This will create one additional field for years.
            rowField.AddDateGrouping(eDateGroupBy.Years | eDateGroupBy.Quarters);
            //Get the Quaters field and change the texts
            var quaterField = pivotTable2.Fields.GetDateGroupField(eDateGroupBy.Quarters);
            quaterField.Items[0].Text = "<"; //Values below min date, but we use auto so its not used
            quaterField.Items[1].Text = "Q1";
            quaterField.Items[2].Text = "Q2";
            quaterField.Items[3].Text = "Q3";
            quaterField.Items[4].Text = "Q4";
            quaterField.Items[5].Text = ">"; //Values above max date, but we use auto so its not used
            
            //Add a pagefield
            var pageField = pivotTable2.PageFields.Add(pivotTable2.Fields["Title"]);
            
            //Add the data fields and format them
            dataField = pivotTable2.DataFields.Add(pivotTable2.Fields["SubTotal"]);
            dataField.Format = "#,##0";
            dataField = pivotTable2.DataFields.Add(pivotTable2.Fields["Tax"]);
            dataField.Format = "#,##0";
            dataField = pivotTable2.DataFields.Add(pivotTable2.Fields["Freight"]);
            dataField.Format = "#,##0";
            
            //We want the datafields to appear in columns
            pivotTable2.DataOnRows = false;

            pck.Save();
        }
        return file;
    }
```

I'm using the 'LoadFromCollection' method to load my pivotTable, it receives 3 arguments (which the last one is the one that I'm having problems):

```
public ExcelRangeBase LoadFromCollection<T>(IEnumerable<T> Collection, bool PrintHeaders, TableStyles TableStyle)
```

So, I tried to set both 'OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.**None**' and 'OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.**Custom**' to the dataRange variable but none of the **PivotTables** changed, they all stayed with the **Medium9** style, no matter what style I tried to set on the TableStyle.

*PS. The normal tables had the style changed when I set others TableStyles*

Does anyone know if isn't possible to change the style of PivotTables with EPPlus and it's default is the Medium9 theme? And if it's possible, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is that changing the `TableStyles` parameter in `LoadFromCollection` should not change any of your pivot tables, it should change the normal table that represents your collection.

You see the output of `LoadFromCollection` is a normal table not pivot.

To change style of your first pivot table all you need to do is:

```
 pivotTable1.TableStyle = TableStyles.Dark2;
```

Where you can change Dark2 to any available style you wish.